# Need help on permission application in android

Tags: android

I am new to android development and I was wondering how hard it is to get all the permission details from all the application installed in the device. Afterwards, I would like to disable some permission.

I know how to get all the app data but how do i get the permission as well and later modify it so i can disable it.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering how hard it is to get all the permission details from all the application installed in the device

If by "permission details", you mean "the permissions the application requests", you can get that from [`PackageManager` and `getPackageInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), to give you [a `PackageInfo` object and its `requestedPermissions` field](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions).

> Afterwards, I would like to disable some permission.

That is not possible, except perhaps on a rooted device. One app cannot affect the permissions of another app.

Comment: When i meant by disable some permission, I mean so that when i get all the permission details, I will do another option that allows the user to turn on or off some of permission like internet or other from other application. I know, i cant completely disable it, as u need root access. I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: @NicholasChang: " I will do another option that allows the user to turn on or off some of permission like internet or other from other application" -- that is not possible, except perhaps on a rooted device. Neither you nor the user can affect the permissions of another app.

Comment: How can it be done . will i need to access the manifest file and remove the permission. Maybe, just the extension to read and write. For example, if i got a rooted device.